# Optical diffuser design

Tags: optics

I have a small 3D printed SLA box, about 3.5" x 2.5" x 2". Here is the bottom half:

[image]

And the top half with an LED inside, facing down, placed off-center, about 1.75" above the "floor":

[image]

Here is the isoline plot of light intensity on the floor:

[image]

I would like to design a 3D printed diffuser, which can be placed close to the LED and reduce non-uniformity of "floor" lighting. I'm not looking for perfection, mostly to increase light intensity in the corners on the right. Any clues or references will be greatly appreciated.

Cross-posted at https://forum.image.sc/t/led-diffuser-design-software/66682

Comment: if diffusing light evenly is important, you may have to mold (heat and pressure as a post-processing step might work).  even sla has these non-uniformities due to the growing process.

Comment: @Abel I intend to use SLA non-uniformity as a diffusing feature. Again, I'm striving for some improvement, not perfection. I'd rather compute a reasonable shape of the diffuser than print dozens of random designs.

Comment: in that case, you can try to make it thicker closer to the LED.  the additional material should help diffuse.  if nothing else, it should reduce intensity in the middle.

Comment: @Abel That's the plan, but I'd prefer to have a computational model to play with.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with just a diffuser. I think you will need some lensing.

Comment: @Drew You may be right, but that would be outside of practical solution space - I can't 3D print a lens with a basic printer.

Comment: you could come up with a ray tracing model by running some tests and gathering data.  a bare minimum could be to use the current part, solve for a refraction angle (slant it and take measurements for where highest reading moves as angle changes), then add material such that distance of refracted path internal to your diffuser is the same for all points. - model where intensity is only reduced by distance travelled in diffuser.